# Conversão inválida ao utilizar ponteiros (invalid conversion from 'int**' to 'int' [-fpermissive])

Tags: c, c++

Estou aprendendo sobre ponteiros e alocação dinâmica e não consigo superar este bug. Aparentemente o ponteiro não está aceitando o valor do tipo int, mas não consigo entender o porquê disso ocorrer.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>

struct Inimigo {
    std::string nome;
    int vida;
};

struct Bloco {
    int bloqueado_ou_nao;
};

struct Mapa {
    int A;
    int L;
    Bloco matriz;
};

struct Fase {
    std::string nome;
    Mapa mapa_fase;
    int N;
    Inimigo vetor;
};

Mapa CriarMapa(int  altura, int  largura) {
    Mapa ** mapa_funcao;
    int porcentagem = 0;

    (**mapa_funcao).matriz.bloqueado_ou_nao = new int * [altura];
    for(int i = 0; i < altura; i++) {
        (*mapa_funcao[i]).matriz.bloqueado_ou_nao = new int [largura];
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < altura; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < largura; j++) {
            porcentagem = rand() % 100 + 1;
            if(porcentagem >= 1 && porcentagem <= 20) {
                mapa_funcao[i][j].matriz.bloqueado_ou_nao = false;
            }
            else if(porcentagem >= 21 && porcentagem <= 100) {
                mapa_funcao[i][j].matriz.bloqueado_ou_nao = true;
            }
        }
    }
    
    for(int i = 0; i < altura; i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j < largura; j++) {
            std::cout << mapa_funcao[i][j].matriz.bloqueado_ou_nao;
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
}

int main() {
    srand(time(NULL));
    CriarMapa(4,4);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
struct Inimigo {
    std::string nome;
    int vida;
};

struct Bloco {
    int bloqueado_ou_nao;
};
struct Mapa {
    int A;
    int L;
    Bloco matriz;
};

struct Fase {
    std::string nome;
    Mapa mapa_fase;
    int N;
    Inimigo vetor;
};
```

Essas estruturas que está usando são apenas tipos primitivos: um `Inimigo` tem um valor de vida. um singelo `int`. Um `Mapa` tem um `Bloco` mas um bloco é também um simples `int`.
E aí vem a `Fase`. Ela tem um `mapa_fase` que só tem um `Bloco` que é só um `int`. E vetor é apenas um `int`.

Não há dimensões nessas coisas. Chamar uma variável de vetor ou de matriz não cria um vetor ou uma matriz (C++ não tem matrizes. FORTRAN tem matrizes. C++ tem vetores apenas. E vetores de vetores e tal.

Se quer uma "matriz" no sentido de um vetor de vetores deve construir uma.

```
    Mapa** mapa_funcao;
```

Isso provavelmente não faz o que você imagina. Em C++ pode usar containers, coisas mais flexíveis para essas coisas, como declarar

```
map<int, Bloco>  um_mapa;
```

E um_mapa seria como um dicionário, com um `int` apontando para um `Bloco`. Há outros containers, como listas, vetores e conjuntos, que podem expressar melhor o seu modelo. C++ é muito conveniente para modelar essas coisas.

#### de volta ao programa

```
    Mapa** mapa_funcao;
```

isso declara `mapa_funcao` como um ponteiro. Só isso. E isso é o que se usaria em C. Mas é só um ponteiro. Não cria um vetor ou uma matriz. Não cria nada.

- `mapa_funcao` é `int**`
- `*mapa_funcao` é então `int*`
- `**mapa_funcao` é então um `int`

E essa linha

```
    (**mapa_funcao).matriz.bloqueado_ou_nao = new int* [altura];
```

então não faz sentido, já que `**mapa_funcao` é um `int`. E `bloqueado_ou_nao` é outro `int` então talvez possa explicar melhor o seu modelo e te digo como montar uma classe que descreve a coisa.

Você tentou escrever um programa em C. Pode até funcionar nesse contexto, mas se pode usar C++ deve usar. É muito mais expressiva que C.

O modo como tentou escrever `CriarMapa()` está quase certo, No entanto o simples é usar uma classe ou mesmo uma struct, e em C++ o construtor da classe faz isso, criar uma instância da estrutura.